# ANTLR error: Decision can match input using multiple alternatives

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr, antlr3

I do not see how to handle the error of a ANTLR grammar:

```
****************error message*********
Decision can match input such as "{'+', '-'} IDENT" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
 |---> add: mult (('+'|'-') mult)*;
***************************************
```

This is mostly copied from the example of Scott, but I do not see why his works well but mine got stuck and how to get out of it?

---------------following Sample.g----------------

```
grammar Sample;

options { 
  language = Java;
}


 program
      :  'program' IDENT '='
          (constant| variable)*
          'begin'
          (statement)*
          'end' IDENT '.'
      ; 

constant:
       'constant' IDENT ':' type ':=' expression ';' 
      ;

type: 'integer';

variable: 'var' IDENT (',' IDENT)* ':' type  ';';


statement: 'var' IDENT ':=' INTEGER ';' ;

//expression

term: IDENT |'(' expression ')'|INTEGER;
negation: 'not'* term;
unary: ('+'|'-')* negation;
mult: unary (('*'|'/'|'mod') unary)*;
```

[XXX Errorfor the following line]

```
add: mult (('+'|'-') mult)*;
relation: add (('='|'/='|'<'|'<=') add)*;
expression: (relation ('and'|'or') relation)*;


END : 'end';

CONSTANT : 'constant';

INTEGER: '0'| (('1'..'9') ('0'..'9')*);   

IDENT: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*;

WS: ('\n'|' '|'\t'|'r'|'\f')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misplaced a parenthesis in:

```
expression: (relation ('and'|'or') relation)*;
```

making your grammar ambiguous: the parser cannot decide when it sees a `- IDENT` if it should be a part of an `add`- or `unary`-rule.

For example, your rule `expression` now matches this:

```
relation ('and'|'or') relation relation ('and'|'or') relation
```

i.e., two `relation` rules directly placed after each other. If the parser now stumbles upon input like this:

```
- A - B
```

the parser "sees" two possibilities to parse this input:

### 1 (unary expression & unary expression)

[image]

### 2 (unary & add expression)

[image]

It should be:

```
expression: relation (('and'|'or') relation)*;
```

instead, so the there can never be 2 successive expressions (and no ambiguity!).

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't see why it reports an ambiguity here. (cf my comments for the reply of Favonius) For example, Could you explain how "+x" gives rise to 2 interpretations? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zell, it's not the exact input `+X` (or `-X`) that is ambiguous, but rather ***a part*** of the input. I tried to explain in a bit more detail in my answer above.

Comment: By the way, although it is now clear foo me thanks to your explanation, I still find it extremely hard to figure out the source of the problem guided by its error message. It might be one of the limiations of these fancy parser generators, who knows! Thanks again Bart.

Comment: @zell, agreed, it is difficult to find out _how_ the parser could possibly match input in more than one way. If you get more familiar with parsing languages (and/or ANTLR), it _will_ get easier, but will still mystify you at times. You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

1. It is good to mention the source web page from where you have picked up the code. I think here it is [Antlr3xtut](http://javadude.com/articles/antlr3xtut/).

> This is mostly copied from the example of Scott, but I do not see why
>   his works well but mine got stuck and how to get out of it?

This is because you copied incorrectly.

Instead of correct code as mentioned below:

```
expression
    :   relation (('and' | 'or') relation)*
    ;
```

You have copied:

```
expression: (relation ('and'|'or') relation)*;
```

Are you able to spot the error? For example the placement of `'('` just before the relation. And because of that you are getting the error **`Decision can match input such as "{'+', '-'} IDENT" using multiple alternatives`**:

[image]

**`Solution`**

Replace you expression rule with what is given in scotts sample.

Comment: Thank you Favonius, I did make a wrong copy. I would like to know where did you get that beautiful tree which debugs? To debug a gramma seems to me terribably hard...

Comment: @zell, when you generate a grammar with [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html) (`CTRL`+`ALT`+`G`), ANTLRWorks will complain with the familiar error _"Decision can match input such as "{'+', '-'} ..."_. If you then click the rule that is colored red, the image above will be visible in the Syntax-Diagram-tab. But to be honest, these images often confuse me more, the error message is of more help to me personally. However, debugging an error in an ANTLR grammar often is hard, even if you're familiar with it.

Comment: Confused!  I surely have a wrong reasoning here. Say the input is  "+x".  Start from an expression. We got the expression-> relation-> add -> unary without ambiguity. Then An unary either 1) recognizes the "+" as its ('+' |'-')* part, or 2) tries to use term to continue recognize "+x". If 1) is chosen, it tries to recongnizs the "x" as negation, term and IDENT at last. If 2) is chosen, it gets stuck eventually and thus, it should not report any ambiguity, doesnot it?? Problably I underlined a wrong way that ANTLR works. Please point it out. Thank you very much  for your ideas.